# CKEditor Image Upload Not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, image, file-upload, ckeditor

I am working in java and javascript, using ckeditor4.2 facing one issue while uploading image.

I have gone through following help on stackoverflow itself by @Don Jones

> Start by registering your custom browser/uploader when you instantiate CKEditor. You can designate different URLs for an image
>   browser vs. a general file browser.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
>     filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse/type/all',
>     filebrowserUploadUrl : '/browser/upload/type/all',
>     filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse/type/image',
>     filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/browser/upload/type/image',
>     filebrowserWindowWidth  : 800,
>     filebrowserWindowHeight : 500
> });
> </script>
> ```
>
> Your custom code will receive a GET parameter called CKEditorFuncNum. Save it - that's your callback function. Let's say
>   you put it into $callback.
>
> When someone selects a file, run this JavaScript to inform CKEditor which file was selected:
>
> ```
> window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<?php echo $callback; ?>,url)
> ```
>
> Where "url" is the URL of the file they picked. An optional third parameter can be text that you want displayed in a standard alert
>   dialog, such as "illegal file" or something. Set url to an empty
>   string if the third parameter is an error message.
>
> CKEditor's "upload" tab will submit a file in the field "upload" - in PHP, that goes to $_FILES['upload']. What CKEditor wants your
>   server to output is a complete JavaScript block:
>
> ```
> $output = '<html><body><script type="text/javascript">window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('.$callback.', "'.$url.'","'.$msg.'");</script></body></html>';
> echo $output;
> ```
>
> Again, you need to give it that callback parameter, the URL of the file, and optionally a message. If the message is an empty string,
>   nothing will display; if the message is an error, then url should be
>   an empty string.

Now the issue is

I've followed the instructions below, the the Server is outputting a JavaScript block exactly as above... Problem is that CKEDITOR isn't doing anything with it, the text is simply showing up in the UPLOAD tab, and not switching tabs and taking the URL... I want the image to be display in preview section. Is there a config, or plugin for the callback which I need to make sure is enabled?

Thanks
Please help

Comment: Same here. Just outputs whatever you return in response :( No solution found yet.

Comment: @Ilia Shakitko please check the answer.

Comment: nope, the issue was in returning the answer as "plain/text" instead of the correct one "text/html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ilia Shakitko Hey the solution i got here it is.

> Use CommonsMultipartFile for getting the uploaded file.then convert
>   this file into bytes write it into BufferedOutputStream object.then
>   upload it to your server (S3 / your own server) and then write below code

URL will be the downloaded url

```
String url;

          String script = "<script type='text/javascript'>" 
                        + " window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, '" + url + "', '');" + "</script>";

          PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = res.getWriter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          out.println(script);
```

Comment: Hi Kamini, I'll check it tonight. How did you get to that solution? It's basically more JavaScript code should be output from the backend as I understood. I'll let you know once checked.

Comment: Yes this is code in your controller class. just return this things to your js

Comment: Hi, solution is different in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169920/uploadfile-callback-is-not-being-triggered-in-ckeditor/32190577#32190577