# UploadFile callback is not being triggered in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, image-uploading

I am using latest Full CKEditor (**4.5.3**) with Office2013 style enabled.

I added filebrowserImageUploadUrl option here:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'news_content' ,
            {
                "filebrowserImageUploadUrl": "/path/to/script.php"
            });
```

When an image is uploaded, backed is returning proper HTML and headers to CKEditor, but what it does - just displays that JavaScript code and doesn't actually trigger that. If I copy-paste that JS to the browser (Chrome) console - it works (switches tab to the first one and inputs the image).

Please find screenshot attached. What have I missed?

[image]

P.S> The first argument is taken from the Request when file is being uploaded, so in that case it's = 1 (it's not the issue :))

Comment: Any chance the response is sent with incorrect headers, like plain/text is enforced etc?

Comment: Well, I tried with setting explicitly to "text/html", no result. I have a possible solution. Will check tonight.

Comment: Well, to be honest, Wiktor, I re-checked again headers and probably isolation has mad it's deal. I was explicitly setting headers to plain/text instead of text/html. That's why opensource and working in collaboration - rocks! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was guessed by @Wiktor the issue was in setting proper headers. I was almost there, setting wrong headers.

Right headers are obviously: **"text/html"** (not "plain/text", it recognizes it just as a text in this case)

```
    $uploadResponse = new Response();
    $uploadResponse->headers->set('Content-type', 'text/html');

    $content = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    $content .= "window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" . $funcNum . ", '/uploads/news_image/" . $response['uploadedName'] . "', '');\n";
    $content .= "</script>";

    $uploadResponse->setContent($content);
```

Comment: am facing the same issue can you help me in this

Comment: what is $funcNum?

Comment: @bhavikshah28 It is function number, something that can be scrapped using console. An argument used by CKEditor - see I explained in the original question.

Comment: @IliaShakitko thanks but what I want is the name of the file in the aspx page so that I can save it into a database. I succeeded in uploading the file