# CKEditor can not parse JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, ckeditor

What I have:

1. Symfony2
2. CKEditor with [Image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image) and [Enhanced Image (also image2)](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2) addons

I found information about uploading files to server on [official site](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload):

> Example — Setting Up Image upload plugin:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
config.imageUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php?type=Images';
```

> Response: File Uploaded Successfully When file is uploaded
>   successfully then JSON response with the following entries is
>   expected:
>
> - uploaded – Set to 1.
> - fileName – Name of uploaded file.
> - url – URL to a
>     uploaded file (URL-encoded).
>
> Example:

```
{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "foo.jpg",
    "url": "/files/foo.jpg"
}
```

Symfony returns JSON responce:

```
return new JsonResponse(
            array(
                'uploaded'  => '1',
                'fileName'  => $image->getName(),
                'url'       => $image->getWebPath()
            )
        );
```

After successfully uploaded an image I see:

[image]

And error in JS console:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/json:
>   "http://example.com/app_dev.php/dashboard/settings/upload/image?CKEditor=example_post_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en".

But it must be working like on the [official page](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images) (see second editor)

I tried to return other response from Symfony, like:

```
$response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        $response->setContent(
            json_encode(
            array(
                'uploaded'  => '1',
                'fileName'  => $image->getName(),
                'url'       => $image->getWebPath()
            )
        ));

        return $response;
```

but not works. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

I resolved the problem by using [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169920/uploadfile-callback-is-not-being-triggered-in-ckeditor/32190577#32190577). Final FCKeditor code look like:

```
$response = new Response();

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');

$content = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
$content .= "window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, '".$image->getWebPath()."', '' );\n";
$content .= "</script>";

$response->setContent($content);

return $response;
```

Does anyone know another solution or why solution with JSON response doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show the js code that calls the backend?

Comment: why is there a dollar sign in `$return new JsonResponse`

Comment: @chiliNUT just a copy-paste mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they have in their [example](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images) in the second editor works exactly the same as you put in your **UPDATE**.

In response they have `Content-Type: text/html` and content is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("92", "\/userfiles\/images\/side-nav.jpg", "");
</script>
```

So, there's unlikely to be another solution.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I think have other solution, because you have directly access to CKEditor events.

Comment: If you asking why there is a "92" number set, open this [doc](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)/Custom_File_Browser) to read about it.

Answer (score 6):

The JSON response is used only when you paste an image in the content, for file uploads from the dialogs you must use the normal javascript response

Comment: Thanks @AlfonsoML. What I need write in the response content? What it mean —  **normal javascript response** ?

Comment: the "Normal response" is the one that you've found that works. It has been that way for many years and only the new paste system uses JSON response. You can find that for example in their docs http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api-section-example-4 and in any other site that explains how to upload files in CKEditor